# Printer is printing binary data as ASCII

Tags: drivers, printing, printer, network-printer, print-spooler

One of my users (exec. assistant) has a printer in her office. When she prints to it, binary data is printed as ASCII chars. The blue rectangled item shows my test prints, sent via FTP upload to the printer. I used `\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n` newline chars. They printed as expected.

I don’t know what her two prints were in the red rectangle area. If they're like binary jobs I've uploaded via FTP, past 80 columns/chars, the data is discarded, so she's not wasting a bunch of paper. She's definitely not uploading the data to the printer via FTP.

[image: picture showing test prints and real prints]

My coworkers have removed the printer, added it back, removed the drivers, re-installed the drivers, and nothing seems to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I asked her to have her boss print to the problem printer but he hasn't done that yet to my knowledge. She said printing her stuff to another printer worked fine.

Comment: "I believe she said printing her stuff to another printer worked fine."  this is important.  test this.

Comment: @Keltari, verified she could print to another printer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you just sent plain text for your print job. A PCL5 printer understands and prints plain text. The other job is a PCL6  (PCL XL) job. If that is sent to a printer that supports PCL5 it will probably produce something like the garbage shown in your second image.

So, in order to fix this, install a PCL5 driver instead of PCL6. Alternatively, switch the printer to PCL6 (via its web interface).